# Jenkins pipeline, bitbucket hook and maven release plugin infinite loop

Tags: maven, jenkins, bitbucket, maven-release-plugin, jenkins-pipeline

I haven't been able to find any info about this, so i hope you guys can help me on this one

I've a maven project hosted in bitbucket that has a BitBucket WebHook pointing to someurl/bitbucket-hook/ , this hooks triggers the build of my project that is defined by a pipeline that has this structure:

```
node {
   stage 'Checkout'
   git url: 'https:...'

   def mvnHome = tool 'M3'

   #Various stages here
   ...
   stage 'Release'
   sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -B clean install release:prepare release:perform release:clean"
}
```

the problem is that maven release plugin pushes changes to BitBucket, and this triggers again the jenkins script, making an infinite loop of builds, is there a way to prevent this?

I've tried setting a quiet period in Jenkins with no success

Comment: Modify the webhook to ignore mvn release changes?

Comment: @RobKielty where can you modify the webhook? in the jenkins configuration of the job i just see a checkbox "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" without advanced options, and in bit bucket i just can select the trigger (repository push), is there another place where i can modify the behavior of the trigger/webhook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my perspective you should have specific jobs for build and release, and the release job should be triggered manually. Anyway, if there is some reason to have them in the job you can check for the message of the last commit:

```
node {
  git 'https...'
  sh 'git log -1 > GIT_LOG'
  git_log = readFile 'GIT_LOG'
  if (git_log.contains('[maven-release-plugin]')) {
    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
    return
  }
  ... // continue with release or whatever

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[A New Way to Do Continuous Delivery with Maven and Jenkins Pipeline](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/new-way-do-continuous-delivery-maven-and-jenkins-pipeline) article approach solves the infinite loop:

> Use the Maven release plugin to prepare a release with
>   pushChanges=false (we are not going to push the release commits back
>   to master) and preparationGoals=initialize (we don't care if the tag
>   is bad as we will only push tags that are good)

```
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -DreleaseVersion=${version} -DdevelopmentVersion=${pom.version} -DpushChanges=false -DlocalCheckout=true -DpreparationGoals=initialize release:prepare release:perform -B"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be to change the git hook (post-receive) and add a conditional curl similar to this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
git_log=$(git log --branches -1)
if ! [[ $git_log =~ .*maven-release-plugin.* ]] ;
then
curl http://buildserver:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@server/projects/name.git;
fi
```