# Jenkins declarative pipeline, abort build by regax in git commit message

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, bitbucket

I am working on a Jenkins declarative pipeline deployment with Maven release plugin.
I met the same issue like this post ([Jenkins pipeline, bitbucket hook and maven release plugin infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270738/jenkins-pipeline-bitbucket-hook-and-maven-release-plugin-infinite-loop)) which runs into an infinite loop but this answer is for script pipeline. Any idea to solve this problem for declarative pipeline script?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit this by ignoring the Jenkins user in the bitbucket hook.
 [image: see as per my implementation]